# Search for user in other Active Directory domain

Tags: .net, active-directory

I created one ParentDomain ADDomain1 having a child ADDomain2. In ADDomain2 I created a Group 'Common Users' in this I have users both from ADDomain1 as well ADDomain2, but when I do a directory search for a ADDomain1 user in ADDomain2 it doesn't retuen any result. here is a code

```
DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher();

 DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ADDomain2","UserName","Password");
directoryEntry.Path = "LDAP://ADDOMAIN2/DC=ADDOMAIN2,DC=ADDOMAIN1,DC=WAVEDOMAIN";
directorySearcher.SearchRoot = directoryEntry;
            directorySearcher.FindOne();
directorySearcher.PageSize = 1000;
            directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(name=ADDOMAIN1User))";
SearchResultCollection results = directorySearcher.FindAll();
```

But when I search for ADDOMAIN2 user it returns results.

Any Idea?

Thanx

Comment: I don't think your users from ADDOMAIN1 will be part of ADDOMAIN2 - so you will not find them in that domain... those are two separate domains - their objects aren't replicated from oen domain to the other... I think this is "as designed"

Comment: But When I Search for Group 'Common Users', I get Both AD1 and AD2 users in its member

Comment: But when I search for Group 'Common Users' I get both AD1 and AD2 users in its memebers.

Comment: yes, of course - you have members from both domains. But your `ADDOMAIN2` does **not contain** all those users from  `ADDOMAIN1` - so you cannot search for users from ADDOMAIN1 inside ADDOMAIN2. They can be group members - but they're not part of the child domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about DirectoryEntry, does it work with UserPrincipal? Is AD2 a global catalog?

Sample:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ADDOMAIN2");
var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "whatever");
// you can also find the GroupPrincipal and get its members
```

Comment: Are you talking about 'GroupScope'?? Common Uesrs group is set to 'Domain Locale'

Comment: I don't understand your question. Anyway, I meant create a PrincipalContext, and then try UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity. It's similar to what you're doing, but on a higher abstraction level, I like this way much better.

Comment: Thanx fejesjoco , is there any example for this to which I can refer??